# UIAlertView orientation issue iOS 8 and Above

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation, uialertview, uiinterfaceorientation

My app is constructed using portrait mode only, but videos played in landscape orientation. My issue is that while I playing the video any push notification alert comes it shows in portrait mode, I use the following code snippet to show `MPMoviePlayerViewController`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Anybody please help me.
I've tried different solutions found on SO but nothing is helpful.
**I've tried `UIAlertControler` in the case of iOS8 and above but it doesn't show while playing video.**
My code to add `UIAlertController`

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"New Notification" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *openAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Open", @"")                                   
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:openAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can you post code for how you showing alert controller in iOS 8?

Comment: UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"New Notification" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
UIAlertAction *openAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"") style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:openAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Try to present alert controller from appdelegate  window rootviewcontroller.